# pivot_longer with a very big data.frame, memory efficient approaches

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, large-data

I have a `data.frame` of hospital data with 11 million rows.

```
Columns: ID (chr), outcome (1|0), 20x ICD-10 codes (chr).
Rows: 10.6 million
```

I wish to make the data tidy to allow modelling of diagnostic codes to a binary outcome.

I would normally use `pivot_longer` or Base R `aggregate` function, but the resulting `data.frame` is huge and my machine struggles, due to memory (32gb RAM, windows server running latest R x64).

I am going to split the `data.frame` and `pivot_longer` for each and manually add columns to allow binding `data.frame`'s after, or to model each split `data.frame` separately.

Is there a method I could use instead to reduce the data size or achieve a similar objective which I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `data.table::melt` instead:

```
library(data.table)

DF <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS, replicate(10, sample(0:1, 26, rep=TRUE)))
setDT(DF)
melt(DF, id.vars = "ID")
```

library([data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)) provides a high-performance version of base R's `data.frame` (focus on speed and memory efficiency).

Please also see this [related benchmark](https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/).

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try. I am interested to know if there is another way of handling large datasets, to create tidy data apart from reshaping?

Comment: @JisL it all depends on the context. If e.g. your modeling function requires a certain format regarding its input data there is no way getting around reshaping.

Comment: @JisL did it help?

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately it still throws an error as the resulting DT has >6k columns. I am trying a split, melt, combine method at the moment.

Comment: For this library([disk.frame](https://github.com/DiskFrame/disk.frame)) or library([arrow](https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/r)) might be of interest. Please check: [vignette("dataset", package = "arrow")](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/dataset.html#processing-data-in-batches).